# How to create gradle project with multiple root project in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

So the idea is to add a new gradle project in hierarchy, at root level. All spring-boot sub modules will extend its build.gradle.

1. Should I use multiple build.gradle ?
2. settings.gradle should contain multiple hierarchy. Is it possible ?

A sample hierarchy is described below to explain.

```
     -> b
    /
a ->
    \
     -> c

     -> q
    /
p ->
    \
     -> r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me which hierarchy you mean.

If you mean the project structure hierarchy, in other words, to have a single Gradle build plan, in other words, have a single structure and a single `gradlew` execution to build both trees, that what you want is impossible. Citing the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html), emphasis mine:

> A multi-project build in gradle consists of **one root project**, and one or more subprojects that may also have subprojects.

The work-around, in this case, would be just stick another Gradle project on top of is, so that you have a proper root again:

```
           -> b
          /
      a ->
     /    \
    /      -> c
z ->
    \      -> q
     \    /
      p ->
          \
           -> r
```

---

If you mean to add two *gradle* roots to the root dir of a single *git* project, I suppose you could do that by using different `xxx.gradle` file names, but I think this will get very awkward to use, and I advise against it. Just use subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks for providing alternate approach and citing the above limitation.